# Docker swarm stack ignores postgres password env variable

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to deploy postgres and pgadmin as a swarm stack via `docker stack deploy` with this compose file

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=87654321
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    ports:
     - "5433:80" 
    environment:
     - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=developer@happycode.io
     - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=12345678
    depends_on:
     - postgres 
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

With `docker stack deploy` - **POSTGRES_PASSWORD** is never applied to postgres, I can `echo` env variable inside the container and it contains correct value `87654321` but postgres still uses the default one. However if I use the same compose file with `docker-compose` everything works fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the volume `postgres-data` has already all the data required for `postgres`.

try to delete it first and re-deploy the stack.

```
docker-compose down --remove-orphans --volumes
```

or stop the `stack` and run:

```
docker volume rm postgres-data
```